# How to construct a simple BL when DL needs to return BL types

Tags: c#

I've got my DL project abstraction (seperate assmebly for my DL)  I've got a BL (seperate assembly)..where it's got intermediate methods that are calling some db layer methods.  But some of those DL methods need to return a type that's in my BL...that would force a problem, a circular reference.  How are you handling this in terms of patterns?

so for instance if I have a hypothetical MyProject.DL has the following method in the Car class:

```
internal List<Car> GetCars(Dealer dealer)
{
   // logic

}
```

and MyProject.BL needs to call that DL method:

```
public List<Car> GetCars(Dealer dealer)
{
     MyProject.DL.GetCars(dealer);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd personally separate it out so I had *three* assemblies:

- My.Project.DL
- My.Project.BL
- My.Project.Types

I'd put any shared types in the `My.Project.Types` library, as long as they *contained no logic of their own* and were only populated/manipulated by methods in the DL and BL libraries.

For example:

In `My.Project.Types`

```
namespace My.Project
{
    public sealed class Car()
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string CarName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now both `My.Project.DL` and `My.Project.BL` would reference the `My.Project.Types` assembly and thus obtain the `Car` type from there. Note that I haven't namespaced the `Car` class into a namespace called `My.Project.Types` because that namespace would be spurious and somewhat pointless, instead I've left them in `My.Project` which makes much more sense.

Comment: so basically your Types layer is like a repository pattern?  or what?  I mean you are holding the "structure" of the types in Types right?  And then your DL is making calls and returning My.Project.Types? or is your BL calling methods like GetCars in your My.Project.Types and then it calls your DL.GetCars ?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, there are no methods in `My.Project.Types` just clases like `Car`, so **both** the DL and the BL take a reference to Types, so they can share the classes

Comment: Ok, but I have a Car type in my BL that represents a car.  The data in my Database is not an exact mirror of my BL object..cause I add other properties and methods (logic) in my BL Car class.

Comment: If the two types aren't the same, then you can't share them, unless you accept that your DL will leave your `Car` partially constructed and it won't be of any use until it's been fleshed out by going through the code in youR BL. That said, as I said initially, if they're fundamentally not the same then you should keep them distinct.

Comment: well your BL objects really shouldn't be mirroring your exact Data Object anyway right?  I mean that's bad design?  I guess that's called Domain Driven Development?

Comment: It depends (as ever! =) ... if some of them are identical then it makes little sense to have two types that are exactly the same, but if some differ then that's fine too

Comment: Rob what are you calling your Types classes (DTOs I think right?) vs. your DL classes?  I was thinking I could do [EntityName]DL.cs for my DL classes and [EntityName]DTO.cs for my DTO class names.  This clearly shows you what's goign on in code when you use them but also keeps you from having to worry about namespace conflicts.  The BL method will just be called [EntityName].cs  for whatever entity you're creating

Comment: So really Types are your "DTO" classes that just hold the structure of the database type.  I like this...just what JanW was explaining in addition to your info.

Comment: The class in `My.Project.Types` don't do *anything* in and of themselves, they get populated from the datbase and saved to the database by methods in the DL (for example: `public Car LoadCar(int carId)` and `public void SaveCar(Car car)`) and manipulated by methods in the BL (for example: `public void AssignOwnerToCar(Car car, Person owner)` which would modify the `Person` object) .. these examples are a bit contrived but I hope you get my gist =)

Comment: man this rocks...finally.  I get a clear way to go about this.  So is this

Comment: "if some of them are identical then it makes little sense to have two types that are exactly the same, but if some differ then that's fine too ".  I don't understand what you're referring to.  Are you saying it doesn't make sense for example to have MyBL.Customer and MyDL.Customer classes?

Answer (score 3):

If your app is big enough, create a seperate project for DTOs (your return types), which the DL and the BL both have a refrence to.

Brian

Comment: yea figured I'd have to do another layer but what do you call that a repository layer?

Comment: what do you mean by big enough.  I will not create projects without a 3-layer setup at the least.

Answer (score 1):

A data layer should do nothing else then reading or writing your data. Knowing types of your business logic would infact harm this rule deeply.
If you have to return those types anyway, you should either use an interface in the middle, or extract the type to a seperate library.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we have both the DTO's (the types) and the DAL classes for each of the types in the same assembly but grouped differently under varying namespaces.
The types themselves are DTO's as in they only contain the structure of the class. The DAL classes have the persistence  logic and the business layer uses the DTO's.

Like a lot of people have mentioned above, you could just as well move the types into a separate assembly but this is working just as fine for us.

From a calling perspective, the Business layer will invoke the corresponding DAL to save / retrieve its data and the DAL will make the calls to populate the types with information / persist the information and then return the types to the Business Entities.

**EDIT - added an Example**

Business Entity object - UserBE

DAL class - UserDA

DTO - UserDTO

To populate users information, userBE will call userDA - which returns a userDTO populated with the requested information. This userDTO is used to inflate the userBE object - which is the business entity - now filled with data for a specific instance.

All naming conventions are only for understanding!! ;-)

Comment: yea but what if one of your DL methods needs to return the same business type?  that would create a circular reference

Comment: the DL methods only return the DTO's - never the business types. The DTO's are in the same assembly as the DL methods.
The Business layer references this assembly - thats the only top down reference...does that clarify?

Comment: Ah, interesting, just another way to go about it.  Nice.  You're seperating but just not physically with your DTOs.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Exactly. Just a slight twist..same assembly but we separate them logically by putting them in 2 different namespaces XXX.YYY.Data.Access and XXX.YYY.Data.Contracts. and visually using folders in VS.